# "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous" when trying to train a new JAX+Equinox model a second time

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, jax

**TL;DR**: I create a new instance of my `equinox.Module` model and fit it using Optax. Everything works fine. When I create a *new* instance of the same model and try to fit it from scratch, using the same code, same initial values, same everything, I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

...somewhere deep in Optax code. My code doesn't compare any arrays. The error message doesn't show where exactly the comparison happens. What's wrong?

### Code

```py
# 1. Import dependencies.
import jax; jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)
import jax.numpy as np, jax.random as rnd, equinox as eqx
import optax

# 2. Define loss function. I'm fairly confident this is correct.
def npdf(x, var):
    return np.exp(-0.5 * x**2 / var) / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * var)

def mixpdf(x, ps, vars):
    return ps.dot(npdf(x, vars))

def loss(model, series):
    weights, condvars = model(series)
    return -jax.vmap(
        lambda x, vars: np.log(mixpdf(x, weights, vars))
    )(series[1:], condvars[:-1]).mean()

# 3. Define recurrent neural network.
class RNNCell(eqx.Module):
    bias: np.ndarray
    Wx: np.ndarray
    Wh: np.ndarray
    def __init__(self, ncomp: int, n_in: int=1, *, key: np.ndarray):
        k1, k2, k3 = rnd.split(key, 3)
        self.bias = rnd.uniform(k1, (ncomp, ))
        self.Wx = rnd.uniform(k2, (ncomp, n_in))
        self.Wh = 0.9 * rnd.uniform(k3, (ncomp, ))

    def __call__(self, vars_prev, obs):
        vars_new = self.bias + self.Wx @ obs + self.Wh * vars_prev
        return vars_new, vars_new

class RNN(eqx.Module):
    cell: RNNCell
    logits: np.ndarray
    vars0: np.ndarray = eqx.field(static=True)

    def __init__(self, vars0: np.ndarray, n_in=1, *, key: np.ndarray):
        self.vars0 = np.array(vars0)
        K = len(self.vars0)
        self.cell = RNNCell(K, n_in, key=key)
        self.logits = np.zeros(K)

    def __call__(self, series: np.ndarray):
        _, hist = jax.lax.scan(self.cell.__call__, self.vars0, series**2)
        return jax.nn.softmax(self.logits), abs(hist)

    def condvar(self, series):
        weights, variances = self(series)
        return variances @ weights

    def predict(self, series: np.ndarray):
        return self.condvar(series).flatten()[-1]

# 4. Training/fitting code.
def fit(model, logret, nepochs: int, optimizer, loss):
    loss_and_grad = eqx.filter_value_and_grad(loss)
    
    @eqx.filter_jit
    def make_step(model, opt_state):
        loss_val, grads = loss_and_grad(model, logret)
        updates, opt_state = optimizer.update(grads, opt_state)
        model = eqx.apply_updates(model, updates)
        return loss_val, model, opt_state

    opt_state = optimizer.init(model)
    for epoch in range(nepochs):
        loss_val, model, opt_state = make_step(model, opt_state)
    print("Works!")
    return model

def experiment():
    series = rnd.normal(rnd.PRNGKey(8), (100, 1))
    model = RNN([0.4, 0.6, 0.8], key=rnd.PRNGKey(8))
    return fit(model, series, 100, optax.adam(0.01), loss)

# 5. Run the exact same code twice.
experiment() # 1st call, works
experiment() # 2nd call, error
```

### Error message

```
> python my_RNN.py
Works!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/forcebru/test/my_RNN.py", line 75, in <module>
    experiment() # 2nd call, error
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/test/my_RNN.py", line 72, in experiment
    return fit(model, series, 100, optax.adam(0.01), loss)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/test/my_RNN.py", line 65, in fit
    loss_val, model, opt_state = make_step(model, opt_state)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/equinox/_jit.py", line 206, in __call__
    return self._call(False, args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/equinox/_module.py", line 935, in __call__
    return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/equinox/_jit.py", line 200, in _call
    out = self._cached(dynamic_donate, dynamic_nodonate, static)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 179, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 248, in cache_miss
    outs, out_flat, out_tree, args_flat, jaxpr, attrs_tracked = _python_pjit_helper(
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 136, in _python_pjit_helper
    infer_params_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 325, in infer_params
    return pjit.common_infer_params(pjit_info_args, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 495, in common_infer_params
    jaxpr, consts, out_shardings, out_layouts_flat, attrs_tracked = _pjit_jaxpr(
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 1150, in _pjit_jaxpr
    jaxpr, final_consts, out_type, attrs_tracked = _create_pjit_jaxpr(
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 350, in memoized_fun
    ans = call(fun, *args)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 1089, in _create_pjit_jaxpr
    jaxpr, global_out_avals, consts, attrs_tracked = pe.trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic(
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/profiler.py", line 336, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2314, in trace_to_jaxpr_dynamic
    jaxpr, out_avals, consts, attrs_tracked = trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic(
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/interpreters/partial_eval.py", line 2336, in trace_to_subjaxpr_dynamic
    ans = fun.call_wrapped(*in_tracers_)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/linear_util.py", line 192, in call_wrapped
    ans = self.f(*args, **dict(self.params, **kwargs))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/equinox/_jit.py", line 49, in fun_wrapped
    out = fun(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/test/my_RNN.py", line 59, in make_step
    updates, opt_state = optimizer.update(grads, opt_state)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/optax/_src/combine.py", line 59, in update_fn
    updates, new_s = fn(updates, s, params, **extra_args)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/optax/_src/base.py", line 337, in update
    return tx.update(updates, state, params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/optax/_src/transform.py", line 369, in update_fn
    mu_hat = bias_correction(mu, b1, count_inc)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/traceback_util.py", line 179, in reraise_with_filtered_traceback
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 248, in cache_miss
    outs, out_flat, out_tree, args_flat, jaxpr, attrs_tracked = _python_pjit_helper(
                                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 136, in _python_pjit_helper
    infer_params_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/api.py", line 325, in infer_params
    return pjit.common_infer_params(pjit_info_args, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/pjit.py", line 491, in common_infer_params
    canonicalized_in_shardings_flat, in_layouts_flat = _process_in_axis_resources(
                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 4, in __eq__
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 745, in __bool__
    check_bool_conversion(self)
  File "/Users/forcebru/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jax/_src/core.py", line 662, in check_bool_conversion
    raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one element is "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

### Problem

- The error message says `File "<string>", line 4, in __eq__`, which doesn't help.
- It refers to the line `mu_hat = bias_correction(mu, b1, count_inc)` in Optax code, but as far as I understand, it [doesn't compare any arrays](https://github.com/google-deepmind/optax/blob/8e4aa35dec085e9646dc6d633fe914a691ffbac4/optax/_src/transform.py#L110).
- It also refers to JAX code that's supposedly responsible for JIT compilation, but this seems outside my control.

Is there a bug in my model definition (`RNNCell` or `RNN`)? Did I implement the training loop wrong? I basically copied it straight from [Equinox docs](https://docs.kidger.site/equinox/examples/train_rnn/), so it should be fine. Why does it work when I call `experiment()` the first time, but not the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is a bug in `equinox`. The function `_process_in_axis_resources` is decorated in `functools.lru_cache`, meaning that all inputs are checked for equality with arguments from the previous call. On the second run, this triggers a call to `equinox.Module.__eq__`, which raises the error. You can see this problem by doing the equality check directly:

```py
model = RNN([0.4, 0.6, 0.8], key=rnd.PRNGKey(8))
model2 = RNN([0.4, 0.6, 0.8], key=rnd.PRNGKey(8))
model == model2
# ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I would suggest reporting this bug at https://github.com/patrick-kidger/equinox/issues

You could probably work around this issue by not storing a numpy array (`vars0`) as a static attribute. I suspect that equinox assumes that all static attributes are hashable, and numpy arrays are not.

**Edit:** I just checked, and changing this:

```py
vars0: np.ndarray = eqx.field(static=True)
```

to this:

```py
vars0: np.ndarray
```

resolves the issue.

**Edit 2:** Indeed it looks like static fields in equinox must be hashable, so this is not an equinox bug but rather a usage error (see the discussion at https://github.com/patrick-kidger/equinox/issues/154#issuecomment-1561735995). You might try storing `vars0` as a tuple (which is hashable) rather than an array (which isn't).

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, seems like a bug... As for "resolves the issue": true, but then `vars0` becomes a "trainable" vector, but this is exactly what I _don't_ want. However, it seems like these initial values don't affect the results much, so it's probably fine.

Comment: "JAX arrays can never be `static_fields`" - well then, I guess I'm using this completely wrong, good to know